# Choose proper async method for batch processing for max requests/sec

Tags: node.js, async.js, node-async

I need to perform a cyclic call to some external API with some delay, to prevent from 'User Rate Limit Exceeded' restriction.

Google Maps Geocoding API is sensitive to 'req/sec', allowing 10 req/sec. I should make geocoding for hundreds of my contacts, and such delay is required. So, I need have a 10 async geocoding functions with post-delay in 1 sec for each. So, I collect all contacts in array, and then I loop through array in async manner.

Generally, I need to have a N simultaneous threads, with a delay in D msecs in the end of each thread. Entire loop iterates over an array of User entities. Each thread process single entity, as usual.

I suppose to have a code like:

```
const N = 10;   # threads count
const D = 1000; # delay after each execution

var processUser = function(user, callback){ 
  someBusinessLogicProc(user, function(err) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      return callback(err);
    }, D);
  });      
 }

 var async = require('async') ;
 var people = new Array(900);

 async.batchMethod(people, processUser, N, finalCallback);
```

---

In this pseudocode `batchMethod` is a method that I am asking for.

Comment: FYI, node.js has only ONE actual thread for running Javascript.  It sounds like you want to have N async operations in flight at the same time.  In node.js, that is not accomplished with N threads so your terminology is not correct here.

Comment: Does `someBusinessLogic()` provide a callback when it is done?  Or when it has an error?  If not, it should be changed to provide one.  Then, you don't have to guess when it might be done and you can actually code for handling errors.

Comment: #jfriend00 : sure, you right. I updated the code above. Thanks for terminology tip also!

Comment: What are the actual restrictions you must stay within to avoid your `User Rate Limit Exceeded` problem?  Is it a certain number of requests/sec or number of requests at the same time?  You've proposed a partial solution, but haven't described the actual requirements.  This is a bit of the [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).  We can help better if you describe the actual requirements and let us propose a solution that meets those requirements.

Comment: Are you iterating over your people Array?  Are you collecting results?  Please describe in more detail.

Comment: # jfriend00 :  Google Maps Geocoding API is sensitive to 'req/sec', allowing 10 req/sec. I should make geocoding for hundreds of my contacts, and such delay is required. So, I need have a 10 async geocoding functions with post-delay in 1 sec for each. So, I collect all contacts in array, and then I loop through array in async manner.

Comment: Please add this info to your question using the "edit" link.  So, 10 req/sec is the limit.  OK, much simpler problem with that info.

Comment: I updated the question

Answer (score 5):

Putting a delay on the results is not really what you want.  Instead, you want to keep track of what you've sent and when you sent it so as soon as you fall under the requests per second boundary, you can send another request.

---

Here's a general concept for a function that will control rate limiting for you to a fixed number of requests per second.  This uses promises and requires that you supply a request function that returns a promise (if you aren't using promises now, you just need to wrap your request function in a promise).

```
// pass the following arguments:
//   array - array of values to iterate
//   requestsPerSec - max requests per second to send (integer)
//   maxInFlight - max number of requests in process at a time
//   fn - function to process an array value
//        function is passed array element as first argument
//        function returns a promise that is resolved/rejected when async operation is done
// Returns: promise that is resolved with an array of resolves values
//          or rejected with first error that occurs
function rateLimitMap(array, requestsPerSec, maxInFlight, fn) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        var index = 0;
        var inFlightCntr = 0;
        var doneCntr = 0;
        var launchTimes = [];
        var results = new Array(array.length);

        // calculate num requests in last second
        function calcRequestsInLastSecond() {
            var now = Date.now();
            // look backwards in launchTimes to see how many were launched within the last second
            var cnt = 0;
            for (var i = launchTimes.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                if (now - launchTimes[i] < 1000) {
                    ++cnt;
                } else {
                    break;
                }
            }
            return cnt;            
        }

        function runMore() {
            while (index < array.length && inFlightCntr < maxInFlight && calcRequestsInLastSecond() < requestsPerSec) {
                (function(i) {
                    ++inFlightCntr;
                    launchTimes.push(Date.now());
                    fn(array[i]).then(function(val) {
                        results[i] = val;
                        --inFlightCntr;
                        ++doneCntr;
                        runMore();
                    }, reject);
                })(index);
                ++index;
            }
            // see if we're done
            if (doneCntr === array.length) {
                resolve(results);
            } else if (launchTimes.length >= requestsPerSec) {
                // calc how long we have to wait before sending more
                var delta = 1000 - (Date.now() - launchTimes[launchTimes.length - requestsPerSec]);
                if (delta >= 0) {
                    setTimeout(runMore, ++delta);
                }

            }
        }
        runMore();
    });
}
```

Example Usage:

```
rateLimitMap(inputArrayToProcess, 9, 20, myRequestFunc).then(function(results) {
    // process array of results here
}, function(err) {
    // process error here
});
```

A more advanced version of this function called `rateMap()` is [here on Github](https://github.com/jfriend00/async-utils/blob/master/rateMap.js).

---

The general idea behind this code is this:

1. You pass in an array to iterate through
2. It returns a promise who's resolved value is an array of results (in order)
3. You pass a max number of requestsPerSec to ever hit
4. You pass a max number of requests in flight at the same time
5. You pass a function that will be passed an element from the array that is being iterated and must return a promise
6. It keeps an array of timestamps when a request was last sent.
7. To see if another request can be sent, it looks backwards in the array and counts how many requests were sent in the last second.
8. If that number is lower than the threshold, then it sends another one.
9. If that number meets the threshold, then it calciulates how long you have to wait to send another one and set a timer for that amount of time.
10. Upon completion of each request, it checks to see if it can send more
11. If any request rejects its promise, then the returned promise rejects immediately.  If you don't want it to stop upon first error, then modify your passed in function to not reject, but to resolve with some value that you can identify as a failed request later when processing the results.

Here's a working simulation: https://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/3gr0tq7k/

Note: If the `maxInFlight` value you pass in is higher than the `requestsPerSec` value, then this function will basically just send requestsPerSec requests and then one second later, send another requestsPerSec requests since that's the quickest way to stay under the `requestsPerSec` boundary.  If the `maxInFlight` value is the same or lower than `requestsPerSec` then it will send `requestsPerSec` and then as each request finishes, it will see if it can send another one.

Comment: #jfriend00: thanks! it looks opportunely. However, one more question I have: is there any similar choice for async module usage for this logic? Promise is not the solution I asked for, ((

Comment: @Vitalyp -The async module does not have a rate limiter feature.  It has features that control the number of requests in flight at the same time, but not the number of requests per second.  You can easily take this logic and change the promises to callbacks, but I don't know of any reason to use the async library for this.  I find promises to be so much easier to code and particularly propagate errors properly that I always use them for async coding now that they standard in ES6.  If you're doing much async coding, it would benefit you to use them.  It takes minutes to wrap a func in a pomise.