# error:TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "path" argument must be of type string. Received undefined when trying node utils/nftport/uploadFiles.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I got this error while i try this command: node utils/nftport/uploadFiles.js
I am new to this forum.

Here is uploadFiles.js code:

```
const FormData = require('form-data');
const fetch = require("node-fetch");
const path = require("path");
const basePath = process.cwd();
const fs = require("fs");


fs.readdirSync(`${basePath}/build/images`). forEach(file => {
  const formData = new FormData();
  const fileStream = fs.createReadStream(`${basePath}/build/images/${file}`)
  formData.append("file", fileStream);
  
  let url = "https://api.nftport.xyz/v0/files";

let options = {
  method: "POST",
  headers: {
    Authorization: "bla bla ",
  },
  body: formData
};

fetch(url, options)
  .then((res) => res.json())
  .then((json) => {
    const fileName = path.parse(json.file_name).name;
    let rawdata = fs.readFileSync(`${basePath}/build/json/${fileName}.json`);
    let metaData = JSON.parse(rawdata);

    metaData.file_url = json.ipfs_url;

    fs.writeFileSync(`${basePath}/build/json/${fileName}.json`, JSON.stringify(metaData, null, 2));

    console.log(`${json.file_name} uploaded & ${fileName}.json updated!`);
  })
  .catch((err) => console.error("error:" + err));
});
```

package.json file

```js
{
  "name": "hashlips_art_engine",
  "version": "1.1.1",
  "description": "HashLips Art Engine is a tool used to create multiple different instances of artworks based on provided layers.",
  "main": "index.js",
  "bin": "index.js",
  "pkg": {
    "assets": [
      "layers/**/*",
      "node_modules/**/*",
      "src/**/*"
    ]
  },
  "scripts": {
    "build": "node index.js",
    "generate": "node index.js",
    "rarity": "node utils/rarity.js",
    "preview": "node utils/preview.js",
    "pixelate": "node utils/pixelate.js",
    "update_info": "node utils/update_info.js",
    "preview_gif": "node utils/preview_gif.js",
    "generate_metadata": "node utils/generate_metadata.js"
  },
  "author": "Daniel Eugene Botha (HashLips)",
  "license": "MIT",
  "dependencies": {
    "canvas": "^2.8.0",
    "cucumber": "^6.0.5",
    "form-data": "^4.0.0",
    "gif-encoder-2": "^1.0.5",
    "react-dev-utils": "^12.0.0",
    "react-scripts": "^5.0.0",
    "sha1": "^1.1.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/node-fetch": "^2.0.3"
  }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask].

For example start by [searching your error](https://www.google.com/search?q=error:TypeError+%5BERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE%5D:+The+%22path%22+argument+must+be+of+type+string.+site:stackoverflow.com)

Comment: `const fileName = path.parse(json.file_name).name;` is `json.file_name` a string?

Comment: Which line of code is the error happening on?  Have you tried to debug this at all to see what code of yours contributes to that bad value?  Basic debugging steps should be done before coming here and then you should include what you learned from the debugging in the question.

Comment: I have 1000 images and 1000 json files for each.I receive this error for almost all 1000 images,for some it works ok.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the new info you've supplied in comments that:

1. Some images work
2. Most images don't work.
3. You have 1000 images.

Because of the way your code is structured, you will rapidly go into a loop opening 1000 readstreams and starting 1000 `fetch()` requests all at once.  So, since these are non-blocking operations, all 1000 operations will be in process at the same time.

This can cause problems in a number of possible ways:

1. You could be running out of some local resources (file descriptors, system memory, network sockets, etc...).
2. You could be overwhelming the target host by sending it 1000 requests at a time.
3. You could be running into rate limiting by the target host as it looks to defend itself against DOS attackers.

All of these issues can be lessened by running only a small number of requests at once instead of all 1000 at once where small is a number in the 3-10 range.  You could event test the theory by just running one request at a time.

You can test this theory by running the files one at a time:

```
const FormData = require('form-data');
const fetch = require("node-fetch");
const path = require("path");
const basePath = process.cwd();
const fs = require("fs");

async function run() {

    const delayBetweenImages = 500;

    function delay(t) {
        return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, t));
    }

    const files = fs.readdirSync(`${basePath}/build/images`);
    for (const file of files) {
        const formData = new FormData();
        const fullPath = `${basePath}/build/images/${file}`;
        const fileStream = fs.createReadStream(fullPath);
        // log any read errors
        fileStream.on('error', err => {
            console.log(`Error reading ${fullPath}`, err);
        });
        formData.append("file", fileStream);

        let url = "https://api.nftport.xyz/v0/files";

        let options = {
            method: "POST",
            headers: {
                Authorization: "bla bla ",
            },
            body: formData
        };

        await fetch(url, options)
            .then((res) => res.json())
            .then((json) => {
                console.log(`parsing ${json.file_name}`);
                const fileName = path.parse(json.file_name).name;
                console.log(`   filename = ${fileName}`);
                let rawdata = fs.readFileSync(`${basePath}/build/json/${fileName}.json`);
                let metaData = JSON.parse(rawdata);

                metaData.file_url = json.ipfs_url;

                fs.writeFileSync(`${basePath}/build/json/${fileName}.json`, JSON.stringify(metaData, null, 2));

                console.log(`${json.file_name} uploaded & ${fileName}.json updated!`);
            }).catch((err) => console.error("error:", err));

        // you can experiment with how long this delay is and/or
        // commenting it out entirely as it may not be needed
        await delay(delayBetweenImages);
    }
}

run().then(result => {
    console.log("done");
}).catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
});
```

Summary of changes:

1. Modify the code so it runs one request at a time (for testing purposes).
2. Insert a delay into the loop in case rate limiting is an issue
3. Add logging of readStream errors
4. Adding logging of json filename and the parsed filename
5. Improve logging of errors

There still might be a rate limiting problem which you could test by adding a delay to the loop (to slow down the requests).

If you find that slowing things down or limiting the number of simultaneous requests does make it reliable, then you can improve performance by running more than one (but far less than 1000) requests at once.

Several functions that can help you do that [`mapConcurrent()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46654265/promise-all-consumes-all-my-ram/46654592#46654592) (controls how many requests are running at once) and [`rateLimitMap()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36730745/choose-proper-async-method-for-batch-processing-for-max-requests-sec/36736593#36736593) (limits the number of requests per second) can help you.