# Dealing with rate limiting APIs in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await, rate-limiting, yelp

So I need a way to run a function x amount of times in a given second, then wait until the next second to run the next set. I'm using the Yelp Fusion API to call a 'search' https://api.yelp.com/v3/search and then running a details query on each of the search results: https://api.yelp.com/v3/businesses/business_id.

So the first search query returns an array of businesses like this:

```
const businesses = response.body.businesses
for (business of businesses) {
    fetchPlaceDetails(business.id)
}
```

Theoretically I can run fetchPlaceDetails() in an async manner, but going through 50+ results takes too long. Instead, I'd like to run the query maybe 5 times, wait a second (to get past the rate limit), run the next 5, wait a second, run the next 5, etc.

Not sure how to implement this but I figure it's got to be a pretty standard issue to have when using APIs with rate limits. Also, I'm not sure but nowhere in the documentation do I see an actual call/second limit specified, but I'd assume it's maybe 10 requests/second or so?

Comment: What do you mean "*I can run `fetchPlaceDetails()` in an async manner*"? Surely it already is asynchronous, no? Does it return a promise?

Comment: Have you searched for rate limiting amywhere? There's hundreds of examples on stackoverflow alone

Comment: @Bergi I mean I can slap an async in front of it and run them one at a time with no rate limiting issues but it takes a while when you're iterating through 50+ options and waiting for each previous request to finish before starting the next one

Comment: @JaromandaX I have, yeah. Just not entirely sure how it works in this simple case.

Comment: @nickcoding2 You mean slapping `await` in front of it? So that they execute sequentially? That might actually still run into rate limiting, if each request takes less than 200ms you'd have more than 5 per second.

Comment: Array.splice and Promise.all could help.  Along with a delay. What is the rate limit

Comment: @Bergi Yes, I meant await my bad :) Well I didn't run into any issues with it, not sure how long each request was taking but all results returned fine. But yeah it's definitely not a reliable way of getting past the rate limiting. One of the problems is I don't even know what the rate is because Yelp doesn't document it...

Comment: See `rateLimitMap()` [Method for batch processing max requests per second](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36730745/choose-proper-async-method-for-batch-processing-for-max-requests-sec/36736593#36736593) for something that sounds like it would do what you want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I'd like to run the query maybe 5 times, wait a second (to get past the rate limit), run the next 5, wait a second, run the next 5, etc.

Then just do that:

```
const {businesses} = response.body;
for (let i=0; i<businesses.length; i+=5) {
    await Promise.all([
        ...businesses.slice(i, i+5).map(({id}) => fetchPlaceDetails(id)),
        new Promise(resolve => { setTimeout(resolve, 1000); })
    ]);
}
```

This will also ensure that you wait more than one second between the batches if the 5 requests take longer than that.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a "generic" method that checks if storage array contains any data, if it does, it processes *nn* number of items from the array then waits *ii* number of seconds and repeats the process.

```js
const queue = (() =>
{
  let itemsPerStep = 5, //number of items process per step
      intervalSpeed = 5000, //how long to wait between steps in miliseconds
      stopWhenDone = true, //when queue list depleted stop the loop
      prevDate = 0,
      timer;

  const list = []; //queue list

  const commands = {
    add: item => list.unshift(item),
    get list() { return list; },
    clear: () => list.length = 0,
    speed: (val = intervalSpeed) => intervalSpeed = val,
    itemsPerStep: (val = itemNumberPerStep) => itemNumberPerStep = val,
    stop: () => (timer && console.log("stopped"), timer = clearInterval(timer)),
    start: (t = true) => (stopWhenDone = t, commands.stop(), timer = setInterval(loop), loop())
  };

  const loop = () =>
  {
    const now = new Date();
    if (now - prevDate < intervalSpeed)
      return;

    if (!list.length)
    {
      if (stopWhenDone)
        commands.stop();
      return;
    }

    prevDate = now;

    let res = []; //example result storage

    for(let i = 0; i < itemsPerStep && list.length; i++)
    {
      const value = list.pop(); //get item from the queue list

      res.push(value); //process value
    }
    
    console.log("processed ids: " + res);
  } //loop()

  return commands;
})();


//generate ids
for(let i = 100; i < 230; i += 11)
  queue.add(i);

queue.start();
```