# How to execute maximum 20 async function every minute?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, async-await, promise

I have an array of objects, and for each object inside the array I want to call an asynchronous function.

However, I should only send 20 requests in a minute.

Example:
`const myArray = ["a","b","aa","c","fd","w"...]`
myArray length is 60.

I used to split myArray into sub-arrays of length 20 each and iterate over each sub-array and call the async function.

Then wait for a minute and then iterate over the next sub-array and so on. However I was doing that manually in a way such as

```
let promise;
let allPromises = [];

// Iterate over subArray1 and call the function for each element
for(let i = 0 ; i < subArray1.length ; i++){
promise = await myAsyncFunc(subArray1[i]);
allPromises.push(promise);
}
// wait for all the async functions to get resolved using Promise.all()
await Promise.all(allPromises);
allPromises = [];
await new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 60000));


if(subArray2){
// Iterate over subArray2 and call the function for each element
for(let i = 0 ; i < subArray2.length ; i++){
promise = await myAsyncFunc(subArray2[i]);
allPromises.push(promise);
}
// wait for all the async functions to get resolved using Promise.all()
await Promise.all(allPromises);
allPromises = [];
await new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 60000));
}


if(subArray3){
// Iterate over subArray3 and call the function for each element
for(let i = 0 ; i < subArray3.length ; i++){
promise = await myAsyncFunc(subArray3[i]);
allPromises.push(promise);
}
// wait for all the async functions to get resolved using Promise.all()
await Promise.all(allPromises);
allPromises = [];
await new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 60000));
}
```

If my array got more than 100 elements that would be an issue.
Can anyone provide a practical way to handle this situation?

Comment: It is confusing that you start with an example of `myArray`, but then show code where you have **multiple** arrays, each apparently with just a value at index `i` which is not defined...

Comment: Uh, just write a loop to do this instead of repeating the code many times?

Comment: Please post your complete, actual code if you need help with simplifying it

Comment: @trincot I fixed my description, please check it again

Comment: @Bergi I fixed the description, please check it again

Comment: That call to `Promise.all` makes little sense. It will resolve immediately as all promises in `allPromises` have all resolved already.

Comment: @trincot I need ```Promise.all```, to finish executing the first 20 async calls before navigating into the other sub-array

Comment: Sure, but they **are** already resovled by the time you execute `Promise.all`. What else is `await` doing with each of them, you think?

Comment: @AliOz Where do the `subArray1`, `subArray2`, `subArray3` etc come from?

Comment: You actually want a `Promise.any` and each time a promise resolves, schedule more work and try to keep your queue of promises full at a length of 20.

Comment: @trincot More concretely, the `promise` variable does not hold a promise, since the promise has already been `await`ed - it will hold the result value. Consequently, `allPromises` is an array of values, not an array of promises; and indeed, the `Promise.all` call is superfluous. Or probably the `await` was not meant to be part of `await myAsyncFunc(subArray1[i]);`.

Comment: That's what I wrote in my latest edit to my answer.

Comment: @trincot Ah, right, I only read your comment "*all promises in allPromises have all resolved already*"

Comment: @Bergi ```subArray1```, ```subArray2```, ```subArray3``` are sub arrays of the original array ```myArray```, each one of the subarrays has length 20

Comment: Yes, that was a misnomer.

Comment: @trincot my issue is not with ```Promise.all```, my issue is how to wait 60 seconds after each 20 async call

Comment: @AliOz Then it sounds like a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37213316/execute-batch-of-promises-in-series-once-promise-all-is-done-go-to-the-next-bat or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72923347/dealing-with-rate-limiting-apis-in-nodejs/72923433#72923433

Answer (score 1):

Your call of `Promise.all` is not necessary as by the time it executes, all the promises of the preceding loop have already resolved. `promises` is not an array of promises, but an array of resolution values.

You should have your values in *one* array, like you presented `myArray`, and then you can just perform a `for..of` loop:

```
const delay = ms => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
const myArray = [...subArray1, ...subArray2, ...subArray3];

for (const value of myArray) {
    await myAsyncFunc(value);
    await delay(3000); // 3 second cooldown
}
```

There is no need to chunk a long array into subarrays of at most 20 elements, since this code inserts a cooldown of 3 seconds after each request, so it is guaranteed that you'll not have more than 20 requests per minute.

If the time to resolve `myAsyncFunc()` is significant compared to those 3 seconds, then you would execute considerably fewer requests per minute. In that case you can start the timer for 3 seconds at the same time as you initiate the request:

```
for (const value of myArray) {
    await Promise.all(myAsyncFunc(value), delay(3030));
}
```

The delay is here intentionally a bit bigger than 3 seconds, so to take no risk of being too close to 20/minute.

Comment: Wouldn't this solution delay 60 seconds after each call of myAsyncFunc?

Comment: Yes, I reduced that to 3 seconds.

Answer (score 1):

A naive way to handle this would be to batch requests and wait for a batch to finish, wait a minute and launch the next batch.

Another way is to batch the first 20 requests, then everytime we get a response, we schedule the next fetch in 60s so we have always have 20 requests in a sliding window of 60 seconds.

Here is how both approaches could be implemented

```
const MAX_REQUESTS = 20;

// let's assume you have a fetchData function that takes dataRequestInfo as a param and builds the fetch from there
async function fetchData(dataRequestInfo) {
  // do your fetch here, process the data and return your model
}

/****** naive batch approach ******/
async function batchRequests(dataRequestInfoList) {
  const batchSize = MAX_REQUESTS;
  const batches = splitToBatches(dataRequestInfoList, batchSize);
  const results = [];

  for (let batch of batches) {
    const start = Date.now();
    const batchResults = await Promise.all(batch.map(fetchData));
    results.push(...batchResults);
    // wait for 1 minutes before next batch
    await new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 60 * 1000));
    // alternatively wait for 1 minutes since the first fetch
    // const duration = Date.now() - start;
    // await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 60 * 1000 - duration));
    // do something with batchResults if needed
  }
  return results;
}

function splitToBatches(arr, batchSize) {
  const batches = [];
  const lastIndex = arr.length - 1;

  let index = 0;
  while (index <= lastIndex) {
    const nextIndex = index + batchSize;
    batches.push(arr.slice(index, nextIndex));
    // in case the last element is in an isolated batch we exit the loop
    if (index === lastIndex) {
      break;
    }
    index = Math.min(lastIndex, nextIndex);
  }
  return batches;
}
 
/****** batch then queue requests ******/
async function batchThenQueueRequests(dataRequestInfoList) {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        let currentIndex = MAX_REQUESTS;
        let processedRequests = 0;
        const results = [];
        const fetchNext = async (result) => {
            processedRequests++;
            results.push(result)
            if (processedRequests.length === dataRequestInfoList.length) {
                // everything was processed let's resolve the promise
                resolve(results);
            }
            if (currentIndex >= dataRequestInfoList.length) {
                // no more data to fetch
                return;
            };
            // wait for 1 minute before next request
            await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 60 * 1000));
            fetchData(dataRequestInfoList[currentIndex]).then(fetchNext);
            currentIndex++;
        }
    
        for (let i = 0; i < MAX_REQUESTS; i++) {
            fetchData(dataRequestInfoList[i]).then(fetchNext);
        }
    });
}
```